# Project build failed in release mode, runs fine in debug mode

Tags: gdb, segmentation-fault

I have a big project solution that I am trying to execute, it builds perfectly fine in both release as well as debug mode. The problem is when I try to execute it the debug one is fine but release mode creates segmentation fault and creates a core dump.

Now can anyone help me about how to find out the line number in the code that might have caused the segmentation fault. I tried using gdb but couldn't do much.

Answer (score 2):

> Now can anyone help me about how to find out the line number in the code that might have caused the segmentation fault.

Not with the information you've provided (which is insufficient).

You should read GDB documentation. Here is a good place to [start](http://shop.fsf.org/product/debugging-gdb-gnu-source-level-debugger-10/).

You should load the executable and core into GDB, and use `where` command to fund out which function you are crashing in.

Since the crash only happens in "release mode", you'll need to figure out how to add `-g` flag to your release mode build. Once you've done that, GDB will tell you the file and line number where the crash happens.

Comment: I have already tried options that you have mentioned above, mine being a huge project it doesnt show the line number else for a small code it does.I have tried that also.